# osticket Due Date

Tags: php, database, osticket

Hello Im running osTicket ver 1.12, mysql 5.5.64, and php 7.0.33.

I notice when I add a due date as an agent or admin the due date shows up in the dashboard under "My tickets". I added a "Due date" in forms but when a user fills this information out it doesn't show up in the same column. Also when I open the ticket I can see there are 2 due date sections one for agents and one for users.

Is there a way to allow users to set due dates so I can see them in the panel? I can change it later if I wish.

[image]
  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched the internet on forums and Github and could not find anyone that has been able to post a serious response. I finally figured it out.

I had to add the date field in a "built-in" form, I used the "Additional request information" form and added a date field, in the variable box i put "test_duedate". Then in the DB I found "ost_queue_column" and changed the "duedate" to "cdata__test_duedate". That allowed for the duedate from the "additional request information" form to populate in the queue field "Due Date".

I still had an issue with trying to sort the queue. So I went back to the DB in "ost_queue_sort" and changed "Due Date" to "-cdata__test_duedate". Now it is functioning properly. I hope this helps someone as I was frustrated for days trying to find some kind of info on the internet.